# Run a function repeatedly 10 seconds after it has completed (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that uses "post" to get data from the server and process it. Amount of data varies and the function can take a long time to complete (30 seconds). I would like for the function to be called repeatedly but only 10 seconds after it has completed the previous iteration. *Result of the function is stored in a global and is used in the next iteration of the same function.
I've tried setInterval and setTimeout but neither one of those seem to give me the result I'm looking for.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why doesn't setInterval not give you the desired output? Can you explain ?

Comment: Show us your code so we can see whats going ob

Comment: @taesu interval would not work when an Ajax request is involved. OP wants it to be 10 seconds after the call is done and processed.

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo(){
  $.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
      .done(function( data ) {
        // do your stuff with returned data
        // and call itself again...
        setTimeout(foo, 10000);
  });
}
```

Wouldn't this approach work?

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(){
 //do stuff

 setTimeout(a, 10000); //has to be at the end of the execution. If you're doing things asynchronously that's a different story. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

function setTimeout() can be used for this. But the method must be invoked for the first time then the function itself invoke the method again.

```
    function method(){

         console.log('method invoked');
         setTimeout(method, 10000);
    }

    method();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $id = 1;
var Interval ;
$(function(){
      callAjax();//Starts Interval
});

functoin callAjax()
{
Interval =   setInterval(function () {
            try {
                if($id > 0)
                {
                $.ajax({
                    url: _MyUrl + $id,
                    success: function (calbkData) {
                        $id = 0;
                        if (parseInt(calbkData.id) > 0) {
                            $id = calbkData.id;
                            OpenMsg(calbkData.id);
                        }
                    },
                    global: false, // this makes sure ajaxStart is not triggered
                    dataType: 'json'
                    //,complete: longpoll
                });
                }
            } catch (e) {
           //     alert(e);
            }

        }, 10000);
}
```

This is working very fine, for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
function Test()
{
  //Your code here

 setTimeout(Test(),10000);
 //Its used to set time interval after your iteration is run

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Note that there are multiple answers already saying the same thing, and that this code does not work properly as `Test` is called immediately in the function.